# Android App: Address Family not Supported by Protocol

Tags: sockets, android-emulator

I am trying to have my Android application sent Telnet commands over a small network to another device, and whenever I declare the DatagramSocket it throws a SocketException saying: **Address Family not Supported by Protocol**.  Here is my code below:

```
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        sock = new DatagramSocket();  //SocketException created here

        //first message - cmd
        length = cmd.length();
        message = cmd.getBytes();
        packet = new DatagramPacket(message, length, addr, portAddr);
        sock.send(packet);

        //second message - highCMD
        length = highCMD.length();
        message = highCMD.getBytes();
        packet = new DatagramPacket(message, length, addr, portAddr);
        sock.send(packet);

        sock.close();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Send High CMD Error!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("SocketException");
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (IOException e){
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Send High CMD Error!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("IOException");
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Possible solutions I've considered but haven't made work:

1. Emulator needs port redirect through development machine, which ports to use?
2. I'm not using correct version of IP4/6, how is this set?
3. Device uses TCP protocol, maybe I'm using the wrong socket type?

Other Important Info:

1. I've only run this on an Emulator
2. Development Machine correctly sent telnet commands from Command Prompt
3. Network consists of development machine, router, and device.

**UPDATE: 2/9/11**

I've changed this code to the following, but I'm still getting an exception:

```
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(addr, portAddr);

        sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(socketAddress);
        sock.close();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Send High CMD Error!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("SocketException" + e.getMessage());
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

The message from the exception says "Permission Denied."  Does this mean that my device is blocking the socket from connecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've coded this the wrong way.  Telnet uses TCP which uses stream (connection oriented) sockets, not the datagram sockets used by UDP.

Search for tcp examples.

Comment: I've updated the code with your suggestion (see above), but I still get a SocketException when the connection tried to be made.

Comment: I did not!  After adding this below the application packet in AndroidManifest.xml below the application envelope it worked!  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> Thank you @ChrisStratton !